# mysql не является внутренней или внешней командой!

Tags: mysql

"mysql" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом. Как решить?
Добавлял в path путь, которяй нашёл, а именно (C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0) - никак!

Answer (score 4):

Вероятно поздновато с ответом (9 месяцев прошло) но все же напишу. mysql.exe лежит в папке bin, а не в корне т.о. в паз нужно писать **C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin**